# scroll div down on specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple chat application using Ajax and HTML.
Whenever I load new messages, I want to scroll the div to show the most recent message, so I'm doing the following:

jQuery:

```
function SendMessage()
{
    var clientmsg = $("#comment").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (clientmsg != '')
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data:
            {
                email: email,
                message: clientmsg
            },
            success: function (data)
            {

                // Success means the message was saved
                // Call the function that updates the div with the new messages
                UpdateChat();


                $("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation").outerHeight() * 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I use this line to scroll the div down to the maximum:

```
$("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation").outerHeight()*1000);
```

My problem is, it scrolls down to the maximum **WITHOUT showing the new messages**. It scrolls down till the **last message before the new one**. Which is weird, because I'm calling it after updating the chat. Here's the function that updates the chat:

```
function UpdateChat(){
    $.ajax({
              // URL that gives a JSON of all new messages:
            url: "url",
            success: function(result)
            {
              var objects = JSON.parse(result);
              $("#conversation").html("");
              objects.forEach(function(key, index){
               //append the messages to the div
                $("#conversation").append("html here");
              });
            }
      });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the scrolling command is working **outside** of  the ajax call? Essentially assuming the ajax call was successful.

Comment: @thisiskelvin the ajax is successful because the message is saved to the database. the scrolling command works perfectly fine when tested on the console of the browser

Comment: It may be within the `ajax` call, the dom has registered the change in the dom (in terms of the containers new height. A workaround could be to call within a `setTimeout()`, giving time to recognise the change.

Comment: Would you like me to show within an answer?

Comment: If you add the new messages at the top (ie - prepend them instead of append them) then you will have less scrolling to worry about and the newer messages are simply t the top of the list and accessible without scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can use a `setTimeout()` to let the dom update add give some time before scrolling. See code below:

```
function SendMessage()
{
    var clientmsg = $("#comment").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    event.preventDefault();
    if (clientmsg != '')
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data:
            {
                email: email,
                message: clientmsg
            },
            success: function (data)
            {
            // Success means the message was saved
            // Call the function that updates the div with the new messages
            UpdateChat();

            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation").outerHeight() * 1000);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the scroll line inside a `setTimeout()` method to allow about `500ms` for things to update before scrolling down.

jQuery:

```
function SendMessage(){
      var clientmsg = $("#comment").val();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      event.preventDefault();
      if (clientmsg != '') {
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: url,
              data: {
                  email:  email,
                  message: clientmsg
              },
              success: function (data) {

              // Success means the message was saved
              // Call the function that updates the div with the new messages
                UpdateChat();

                setTimeout(performScroll, 500);

              }
          });
    }
}
```

and the scroll function

```
function performScroll() {  
  $("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation").outerHeight()*1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you insert a new element at the bottom, you could use `scrollIntoView` to make sure the new element is visible:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        var lastElement = $('#conversation :last-child');
        lastElement[0].scrollIntoView();
    }
});
```